# Argument should be a vector

Tags: ruby, arrays, vector

I'm trying to use the `statsample` library, but having issues with arrays/vectors.

```
b = [2,3,4,5,6,7].to_scale
# => #<TypeError: Argument should be a Vector>
```

Do you know why I might be getting this error?

**EDIT 1**

Something odd is going on in my environment....

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'statsample'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> b = [2,3,4,5,6,7].to_scale
=> Vector(type:scale, n:6)[2,3,4,5,6,7]
exit

$ bundle exec irb
irb(main):001:0> b = [2,3,4,5,6,7].to_scale
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_scale' for [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:Array
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/brandon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

For some reason `statsample` is not being required when I use `bundle exec`.  I have to manually `require 'statsample` in my code, even though `gem 'statsample` is in my `Gemfile`.

Any thoughts??

Comment: Can you give a link to the Gem you are using?

Comment: @ArupRakshit statsample (1.3.0).  I've updated my question to include some additional details.

Comment: Specifying gem 'statsample' in the Gemfile is just to help manage dependencies (for bundle install).  You still have to require it explicitly in your code.

Comment: I'm using this in a rails environment, which does `Bundler.require` - but still having this issue. Is there something specific to `statsample` that is different from other gems?

Comment: Has my answer been helpful?

Comment: @majioa  There was something going wonky with the Ruby environment. I'm not sure whether or not to accept the answer as I'm not sure it would be helpful for someone finding this later.

Comment: But for now is there the problem exists yet?

Comment: It's working now. But it didn't have anything to do with requiring the gem.

Comment: If you've got an other answer add it and accept

Comment: @majioa no - none of these fixed the issue. You don't HAVE to accept an answer if it would be misleading for future visitors to the question.

Comment: I'm getting the same exact issue with Ruby 2.1.2, gem version 1.3.1. I'm try to exec in pry console, and even requiring files manually.

Comment: The issue is pry and awesome_print -- details here: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/1060. Workaround is to use irb.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the issue:

```
irb(main):004:0> require 'statsample'
=> true

irb(main):004:0> b = [2,3,4,5,6,7].to_scale
=> Vector(type:scale, n:6)[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Please make sure that if you use the `bundler`, put into the `Gemfile` the following:

```
gem 'statsample'
```

And execute the `bundle install`.

Comment: For some reason `statsample` is not being required in my environment, even though it is in my Gemfile. See update to the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, in most cases (for example, writing a gem) you have to manually require the `gem`

Comment: I'm using this in a rails environment, which does `Bundler.require` - but still having this issue. Is there something specific to `statsample` that is different from other gems?

Comment: There was something going wonky with the Ruby environment. I'm not sure whether or not to accept the answer as I'm not sure it would be helpful for someone finding this later... I'll upvote nonetheless.

Comment: There's more to it than this answer. This is the way it should work. But it doesn't for some of us. I'm using Ruby 2.1.2 and gem version 1.3.1.

Comment: The issue is pry and awesome_print -- details here: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/1060. Workaround is to use irb.

Comment: I fixed this: https://github.com/clbustos/statsample/pull/23

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code:

```
module Statsample::VectorShorthands
  # Creates a new Statsample::Vector object
  # Argument should be equal to Vector.new
  def to_vector(*args)
                Statsample::Vector.new(self,*args)
        end
  # Creates a new Statsample::Vector object of type :scale
  def to_scale(*args)
    Statsample::Vector.new(self, :scale, *args)
  end
end

class Array
  include Statsample::VectorShorthands
end
```

So here my guess is:

If it's just `[Array].to_scale`, it should have no problem at all.  Unless you pass any argument to **to_scale**() which is not Vector type, because inside it's calling `Statsample::Vector.new(self, :scale, *args)`, and it's saying "**Argument should be equal to Vector.new**".